# How to use regular expression in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am new to python . I have .txt file which is look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZQg3.png)

You can download the data online in the following link under Download & Use VerbOcean:

http://demo.patrickpantel.com/demos/verbocean/

It is actually a list of verbs and their relationships with another verb.
I want to make a dictionary for each relationship, so that we could say for example

`stronger_than['abandon'] = 'renounce'`

`happens_before['X'] = 'Y'`

Can anyone help me to get started?

Comment: can you post an excerpt of this file as regular text, so it's easier to work with it?

Comment: This problem can be easily solved with a regular expression

Comment: The data is online in the following site under Download & Use VerbOcean 
    [link](http://demo.patrickpantel.com/demos/verbocean/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strongerThan = {}
strongerThan['abandon'] = 'renounce'
strongerThan['like'] = 'fond'
print(strongerThan)
{'abandon': 'renounce', 'like': 'fond'}

input file:
renounce [stronger-than] abandon :: 13.617344
reject [happens-before] abandon :: 11.731130
abandon [similar] reject :: 12.048992
embrace [happens-before] abandon :: 13.295483
```